# What's a word that means "assumes the best in people"?

Tags: adjectives

I would love to find a word that you could ascribe to a person who assumes the best in people.

Thank you!

Comment: An *optimist*, of some flavor.

Comment: Naïve, perhaps.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the best in people is a good thing. It becomes a bad thing, however, when that assumption is proved to be unwarranted and yet is still tenaciously clung to.

Moreover, one's perspective on the level of people's goodness (or badness) is colored by a mindset which could be labelled "glass half-empty" (GHE) or "glass half-full (GHF)."

The GHE person focuses on the exceptions to the "goodness" rule, whereas the GHF person focuses on the good behavior he or she believes is predominant among the "vast majority" of people. Each person then attaches a label to the behavior of others which accords with their respective perspective.

So, what are those perspectives, and what label can we place on the people who have these disparate perspectives?

Well, the GHE person could be described as follows (note that some of the following words have negative connotations and could be used by the GHF person to derogate the GHE person.):

- pessimist
- cynic
- gloomy Gus
- a crepe hanger*
- fatalist
- a "realist"
- (even) misanthrope

More to the point of your question, the GHF person could be described as follows (note that some of the following words have negative connotations and could be used by the GHE person to derogate the GHF person):

- Pollyanna
- optimist
- a person wearing rose-colored (or -tinted) glasses
- a sunny person
- philanthropist
- humanitarian
- idealist
- a "realist"
- positive thinker

Naturally, both the GHE person and the GHF person consider the other person's perspective as unwarranted, unrealistic, unfair, broad-brushed, unjustified/unjustifiable,  baseless, groundless/ungrounded, indefensible, foundationless, and unwarranted/unwarrantable.

```
_________________
```

* In the days when memorial services for the dead were conducted in homes (not funeral homes!), a custom was for the grieving family to hang black crepe outside the house, which signified there had been a death in the family. Hence, a "crepe hanger" is the eternal pessimist and could be considered a GHE kind of person. Interestingly (and apropos nothing), a person is born into the world every three seconds, whereas a person dies and departs from this world every eight seconds. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

> *trusting*
>   ˈtrʌstɪŋ/
>   adjective
>   showing or tending to have a belief in a person's honesty or sincerity; not suspicious.
>   "it is foolish to be too trusting of other people"
>   synonyms: